# Is there a way using iframe or javascript to show our linkedin profile's Recent Updates inside our web site

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, linkedin-api

I am building a .net web application for our company web site. and we already have a linkedin profile for our company, and we always add updates to our linkedin profile, as follow:-

[image]

but my question if i can show those recent updates inside our web site? can i do so using iframe or javascript? of course i do not want to embed the whole linkedin profile page inside our web site, i only need the Recent Updates?

Answer (score 0):

you can use linkedin api for showing them in your web pages

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api

Comment: so i have to build this using javascript which integrates with linkedin api??.. i can not simply do this using iFrame?

Comment: problem is different domains and browser didnt  allow you to read iframe content

Comment: but our company's LinkedIn profile is available for all users, i mean you do not need to be login to LinkedIn to view the Recent Updates .. so if i can get our compnay's LinkedIn profile's recent updates using iframe, then this will work fine with me...

Comment: you can show linked in last update link  /company/...
in your web pages ...
as iframe 
if linked in allow it for different  domains

Comment: yes we can reference iframes from different domains this should not be a problem , this is not an issue.. but not sure if Linkedin provide iframes to show the Recent Updates?

Comment: first you must check linked in allow you to show its side inside your i frame or not ...

Answer (score 0):

Does the recent updates page have a unique URL?

That is, is there a URL for the page which will take a person to the recent updates no matter whether they are logged in to Linkedin, a URL that you can enter in the address bar and always get that page?

If there is, add an iframe to your page, specify the URL as the source of the iframe. You should get the page you want - if there is a constant URL that takes you there.

You an show any page from any domain in an iframe - the security issue is that your page can not interact with the iframed page or get information from it.

It sounds like you merely want to display the page - correct?

The only time you would not be able to get a page into an iframe would be if the author has written a bit of JavaScript to see if the page is being loaded in an iframe when they don't want it displayed in any iframe.

They then reload the page into the browser window so that the page occupies the entire browser window. In other words, the code goes to the page on the other site if the owner doesn't what their pages to be displayed in iframes.

If you do put a page from another domain into an iframe on your site, be sure you clearly label it as a page from the other site - otherwise it might look like you are trying to imply that the iframed page is one of your  pages.

Here's the code I use to break out of someone's iframe:

```
if (top != self) {
     alert("Breaking out of Alien Frameset!\n\n" +
          "Someone is trying to load one of the pages from my website into a frame on their website.\n\n" +
          "This is akin to theft in that it appears that my page is part of their web site. I do " +
          "not grant permission for my pages, or images, to be used in that way. \n\n" +
          "It could be you got here via an image search with Google, Yahoo, Bing, etc. The way they display images makes many people think the images are on the " +
          "search site and makes it simply too easy to copy the images. If you want to view my images, which are all copyright protected, I want you to view them " +
          "on my website.\n\n" +
          "I will now take you to this page on my web site. Please enjoy the site as it was intended to be viewed.")
     top.location.replace(self.location)
}
```